# CSCore - not working for a specific device

Tags: c#, cscore

i'm using CScore to play an mp3 file,

first, i have this on my public partial `public MMDevice SelfDevice;`

next, i get the default playback device with this code:-

```
MMDeviceEnumerator enumerator = new MMDeviceEnumerator();
SelfDevice = enumerator.GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(DataFlow.Render, Role.Console);
```

now `selfDevice` has the default playback device. 
then, i run this code to play an mp3 file

```
 if (CSCore.SoundOut.WasapiOut.IsSupportedOnCurrentPlatform)

                _soundOutToSelf = new CSCore.SoundOut.WasapiOut() { Device = SelfDevice };
            else
                _soundOutToSelf = new DirectSoundOut();

            var source = CodecFactory.Instance.GetCodec(pathToMP3())
                .Loop()
                .ChangeSampleRate(32000)
                .ToSampleSource()
                .AppendSource(Equalizer.Create10BandEqualizer)
                .ToWaveSource();

            _soundOutToSelf.Initialize(source);

            _soundOutToSelf.Play();
            _soundOutToSelf.Volume = 1;
            MessageBox.Show(SelfDevice.FriendlyName);
```

it works, but only when i set my HDMI Audio as my default playback device, it plays no music when my Speakers are on default, also the messagebox is returning the right playback device name, so there's no problem with the  device variable. what's the problem here?

also, i tried to make a new project and run the code there and it worked without any problem, so i reverted to an older version to the project when it was working, but now it's not working either.
i deleted the debug folder and the problem still occurs.

[image]

EDIT: i found out i can fix the problem by changing the assemblyname of the program, but i still don't know why windows is blocking my program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

changing the assemblyname or create a new project fixes the problem, still don't know what's the real cause.